# wp7 check for existing pivotitem in a pivot control

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivot

I want to dynamically create a pivotitem inside a pivot control, but before I do that, I want to check if a pivotitem with the same name value doesn't exist already. Is there a way to do it?
If it doesn't exist already, I would create the pivotitem as follows and make it the selecteditem.

```
p = new PivotItem();
p.Name = name;
p.Header = name;
pivot.Items.Add(p);
pivot.SelectedItem = p;
```

I see the pivot control's Items.Contains(object) method, but I am not sure how I would pass the object which may or may not exist already. Is there a way to just check if the Items collection has a pivotitem with a particular name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use LINQ to query the `Items` collection:

```
bool contains = pivot
    .Items
    .Cast<PivotItem>()
    .Any((i) => i.Name == name);
if (!contains)
{
    // Add new PivotItem.
}
```

Comment: thank you for that, I get an error on i.Name saying 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' is accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found. Do I need to add a cast or anything else? Thanks.

Comment: Apologies for that, I forgot to add the cast to `PivotItem`. I've updated the code in my answer.

Comment: That did it, thanks so much :) I need to start learning LINQ.